# Getting PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean in app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, payment, bug

I'm trying to do the following:

```
$order->setTotalPaid($amount);
$order->save();
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean in /mnt/webdrive/foo.foo-web.net/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46

The payment is returning as a boolean! Not a null, and when I go into the orders page in the CMS, I see that a payment method had been set in the payment information! `Payment Information:  My Wallet Payments`

What's weird is, even when I try setting the payment again with

```
$order->setPaymentMethod('foopayment');
$order->save();
```

It's giving the exact same error!

What is causing this issue?

Comment: check log file. is there any exception like "The requested Payment Method is not available" ?

Answer (score 1):

if the Payment has a deleted flag, it will not be returned by the getPayment method and if there are only payments with the deleted flag, the method will return false:

https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php#L912

Comment: I put a log in the loop. It's not even entering the loop to check if it'd eleted. Why is that happening?